# how to map same value to two different fields in jaxb while marshalling and unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a xml tag Hello for which there is a field like below in my java

`class HelloWorld{
@XmlElement
private String name;
}`

While unmarshalling this successfully assigns Hello value to name variable.Now I want to create a new xml from THIS java object(HelloWorld) for which I am doing the marshalling but in this case I want a xml tag as  instead of  in my xml.
How can I acheive this in Jaxb?

Both Xml are not in my control so I cannot change the tag name

**EDIT:**

Incoming XMl - helloworld.xml

```
    <helloworld>
     <name>hello</name>
     </helloworld>

     @XmlRootElement(name="helloworld)
     class HelloWorld{

     @XmlElement(name="name")
     private String name;

      // setter and getter for name
     }

      JaxbContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(HelloWorld.class);
      Unmarshaller un = conext.createUnmarshaller un();
      HelloWorld hw = un.unmarshal(new File("helloworld.xml"));
      System.out.println(hw.getName()); // this will print hello as <name> tag is mapped with name variable.
```

Now I want to use this hw object of HelloWorld object to create a xml like below

```
    <helloworld>
     <name_1>hello</name_1>   // Note <name> is changed to <name_1>
    </helloworld>
```

I do not want to create another class like Helloworld and declare a variable name_1 in that new class .I want to reuse this HelloWorld class only because just a tag name has been changed.

But I use existing HelloWorld class and try to marshal the object hw like below

```
    JaxbContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(HelloWorld.class);
     Marshaller m = conext.createMarshaller();
     StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
     m.marshal(hw,writer);
     System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

This will print like below

```
  <helloworld>
<name>hello</name>
  </helloworld>
```

but I require

```
  <helloworld>
<name_1>hello</name_1>   // Note <name> is changed to <name_1>
  </helloworld>
```

The reason for this is that the incoming xml before unmarshalling and the outgoing xml after marshalling is not under my control.

Hope this explains.

Comment: It is hard to tell from your question exactly what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide a sample of the output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `<helloworld>
 <name>Hello</name>
</helloworld>

@XmlRootElement(name="helloworld")
class HelloWorld{
@XmlElement(name="name")
private name;
}`
On unmarshalling, this assigns Hello value to variable name of HelloWorld class.

Now I have a object of HelloWorld class.Now I want to use this same object for marshalling to create an xml like below

`<helloworld>
 <name_1>Hello</name_1>
</helloworld>`

Note: the <name> is changed to <name_1>
can I use the same HelloWorld class in some way to achieve this.

Comment: Try the @XmlElements annotation, see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156560/jaxb-2-mapping-different-element-to-the-same-property

Comment: @XmlElements work when we want to unmarshall it.It checks the tag name in xml and assigns the value to variable.My case is of Marshalling.

Comment: Can you provide a SCCE?

Comment: Sorry to say but can you tell what is SCCE? its expansion may be..I haven't heard of it..:(

Comment: It is SSCE and it is Short, Self-Contained Example. In other words a fully functioning class that shows the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question with a code example of my requirement.

Comment: It looks like you are just wanting to rewrite the XML, maybe a XLST transformation would be more appropriate?

Comment: can i do it with JAXB? I do not want to use XSLT..as JAXB is used in my application...

Comment: Is it possible to do with JAXB? can anyone help please..

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1 - Works with all JAXB Implementations

You could use a XSLT transform to transform a `JAXBSource` into the XML you want:

```java
    // Create Transformer
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(
            "src/blog/jaxbsource/xslt/stylesheet.xsl");
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer(xslt);

    // Source
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Library.class);
    JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, catalog);

    // Result
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    // Transform
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/using-jaxb-with-xslt-to-produce-html.html

---

### Option #2 - Works with [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)

**Note:**  I'm the MOXy lead.

MOXy provides a mapping document extension that you can use to override the mappings at the field/property level.  This means you could create one `JAXBContext` on just the annotations, and then a second `JAXBContext` based on the annotations with an XML overrride.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

Comment: Thanks For providing the two options.Actually I was looking for a solution in pure/plain JAXB without XSLT or MOXy due to project restrictions.But XSLT option is a good one to consider.Thanks.