# How to map single tag to multiple fields in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, jaxb2

Is it possible to acheive below in JAXB

```
 msg.txt

<Message> 
 <abc>Hello World</abc>
 <cdf>Dummy</cdf>
</Message>

  @XmlRootElement(name="message")
  class Message{

     public String abc;
     public String cdf;
   }

   class Test{
      public static void main(String args[]){
         JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance();
         Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
         Message m = (Message) u.unmarshal(new File("C:/msg.txt"));
       }
   }
```

Now, I want to have Message object populated with abc = 'Hello World' and cdf = 'Hello'.That is, substring of abc field.

I tried using XMLJavaAdapter for cdf field but in unmarshal method of Adapter class I can only get string dummy as ValueType, ie, value of cdf field.

Can this be possible in JAXB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map `abc` and then mark `cdf` as `@XmlTransient` (to prevent it from being populated as part of the `unmarshal`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="message")
class Message{

     public String abc;

     @XmlTransient
     public String cdf;
}
```

Then you can leverage an unmarshal event to populate the `cdf` field after the unmarshalling is done.  Below are links to 2 different approachs for doing this:

1. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback

---

### Corrections to Your Demo Code

You need to include the `Message` class when creatig the `JAXBContext`:

```
 JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Message.class);
```

Also you need to make sure the name you specify in the `@XmlRootElement` annotation matches the root element name in your XML document.  Currently you have a mismatch the case used for these.

Comment: Thanks Blaise.your answer is spot on.That's what I was looking for.Also,there is this question about JAXB if you can suggest is possible to achieve in JAXB - [JAXB Unmarshalling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444464/how-to-map-same-value-to-two-different-fields-in-jaxb-while-marshalling-and-unma)

Comment: @SCoder - I have added an answer to your other question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444464/how-to-map-same-value-to-two-different-fields-in-jaxb-while-marshalling-and-unma/21266066#21266066

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Message{

     private String abc;
     private String cdf;

     public Message(){}

     public void setAbc(String abc){
        this.abc = abc;
        this.cdf = /*substring of abc*/ ;
     }

     public String getAbc(){
        return abc;
     }

     public void setCdf(String cdf){
        //
     }

     public void getCdf(){
        return cdf;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is a quick workaround,although Blaise's answer is spot on.